# How to create an empty object similar to an object from a array of objects in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have the following array of objects:

```
$scope.users = [
    {
        ID: "1",
        Name: "Hege",
        Username: "Pege",
        Password: "hp",
    },
    {
        ID: "2",
        Name: "Peter",
        Username: "Pan",
        Password: "pp"
    }
];
```

I need to create a similar object with empty values like this,

```
$scope.newUser = {
    ID: "",
    Name: "",
    Username: "",
    Password: ""
}
```

so that I can push it to the same array (`$scope.users.push($scope.newUser);`), to get it look something like this:

```
$scope.users = [
    {
        ID: "1",
        Name: "Hege",
        Username: "Pege",
        Password: "hp"
    },
    {
        ID: "2",
        Name: "Peter",
        Username: "Pan",
        Password: "pp"
    },
    {
        ID: "",
        Name: "",
        Username: "",
        Password: ""
    }
];
```

However, the array `$scope.users` will not always have the array of same objects. I need it to work even if I change the array to something different, for example, like this:

```
$scope.users = [
    {
        SID: "pepe",
        Name: "Peter",
        School: "Primary School"
    },
    {
        SID: "hepe",
        Name: "Hege",
        School: "Junior School"
    }
];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: are you sure that in array will be only objects with same structure? anyway angular not provide method for cleaning object fields, but you can simple write your own function

Comment: Why are you doing this? I know that's not an answer, but it just seems to violate what I would call good programming. Having a set of things contain the undefined thing smells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there's always *something* in the array you want to mimic, get the first object, loop the keys and make a blank object:

```
if ($scope.users.length) {
    var defaultUser = $scope.users[0];

    $scope.newUser = {};
    for (var key in defaultUser) {
        $scope.newUser[key] = "";
    }

    $scope.users.push($scope.newUser);
}
```

Comment: Or if you have a finite number of things, then create the declarations for them. Otherwise this is about as good as it gets.